# What would be the right vote-close option for this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

This question [get intersection & union of two arrays from different documents in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67768044/get-intersection-union-of-two-arrays-from-different-documents-in-mongodb):

- Having 2 questions in a question:

  > **Needs more focus**
  > This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.
- Those 2 questions are duplicate of questions: ***(I don't know it is possible to vote duplicate by 2 questions)***

  - [How to find set intersection of sets between the documents in a single collection in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646534/how-to-find-set-intersection-of-sets-between-the-documents-in-a-single-collectio)
  - [$setUnion to merge array from multiple documents MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291965/setunion-to-merge-array-from-multiple-documents-mongodb)
- There is no debugging, error, or problem information:

  > **Needs debugging details**
  > The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.
- AS per OP's comment we can consider he has resolved the problem from the above 2 duplicate questions:

  > Thanks, That's all I wanted

I am confused about What to do in this situation, What would be the right close option for this question?

Comment: "*There is no debugging, error, or problem information:*" it's not a debugging question. It doesn't say something to the effect of "I tried to do it, and it didn't work". Therefore, the "Needs debugging details" close reason doesn't apply.

Comment: Close it as a duplicate of both questions linked in the comments. (Needs a gold badge holder)

Comment: Perhaps vote to close as a duplicate of one of those, and edit the auto-generated comment to add a link to the other one too.